# How to circumvent the maximum number of timeouts in a workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm-online

When I'm designing a workflow using the built-in GUI, I noticed that after the fifth depth of timeout(*timeout until x minutes, then do...*) I can no longer add more steps. Vertically, I can enter many lines but depth-wise (i.e. to the right) it seems to give me a no-no and I can't add a sixth *wait until, then do...* clause.

Is it possible and I'm experiencing some other problem without realizing it or is it a limitation by design? Can it be worked around? I'm targeting both on-premise and on-line installations.

Comment: @andrewbarber Why the edit? It **is** about Windows Workflow Foundation (WWF)...

Comment: "WWF" is *not* a valid tag, nor is it the correct abbreviation for Windows Workflow Foundation. The abbreviation is WF, but the Stack Overflow tag is the one I added: "workflow-foundation".

Comment: @AndrewBarber Apparently, Google agrees with you. WWF is mostly some kind of organization for animals. That's a surprise - I though it was WCF, WIF, WPF and then - WWF. It'd be more structured that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the steps on the same depth (assuming that you're doing something **besides** the delays) - so they are aligned sideways. That way, you can enter arbitrary many waiting statements (i.e. 12, because that's what I've tested).

As for the five levels of depth, I've never run into a situation when I needed it. I suggest that you post a bounty if you'd like to learn more. But you might want to do that after the new years eve. Right now people are busy with that *life* thingy, not attending the only purpose in life (e.g. logging in onto Stack Overflow).